# How to build FFMPEG with a certain OpenSSL path

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, openssl

I want to build `FFMPEG` 4.4 on my Mac with `OpenSSL` 3.0.

This is because I have a program that needs to be built with `FFMPEG`, which needs to have symbols from `OpenSSL` 3.0, such as `_BN_Copy`.

When I build `FFMPEG` with whatever `OpenSSL` version it scoops off the floor, the program I build with `FFMPEG` dies because there's undefined symbols such as `_BN_Copy` which I have determined is only `OpenSSL` 2.0.7>=. Therefore it is using `OpenSSL` 1.1.1l.

How do I build `FFMPEG` with my `/usr/local/bin/openssl` (3.0.7 blah blah blah) executable?

I have built `FFMPEG` with `--enable-openssl` obviously.

Comment: Are you building with homebrew? Or manually? Homebrew will likely have the right dependencies in the recipe. But check which one the `configure` process picks up, and how it determines which package to use (probably `pkg-config`). Edit configuration files to use your version instead. I can't give a "step-by-step" description, I'd have to do it myself.

Comment: Install OpenSSL 3.0 first.  It only came out 10 days ago, surprised your top-level code is required 3.0-only symbols already.  But, if you install it yourself, your ffmpeg compile should use it, assuming it's compatible with 3.0.